# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_product` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `price` double(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCRE' at line 5

Comment: I wouldn't use a float data type for a price - perhaps decimal(10,2) or int would be better.

Comment: Please explain what your question is rather than just providing plane code

Answer (score 1):

try using float without the number of showing digit

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

and for price could be you need  a fixed decimal length  so  you should use decimal

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_product` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a value in your [`double` specifier](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/double/):

```
`price` double(11) NOT NULL
```

It needs both the total digits and the digits following the decimal.  Something like:

```
`price` double(11,2) NOT NULL
```

Though for currency values you may be better off using `decimal` instead:

```
`price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL
```

As this uses a more fixed precision.  Using a `double` may result in unexpected calculation results from how floating point arithmetic works.